# Children to know when conditional checks have already been done as part of Parent component's prop

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have a `<Hidden>` component that conditionally hides children components based on a `when` attribute (i.e., when=true, children are hidden). Sometimes, a child component requires a certain prop to exist (i.e., requires an `id` of type `string`). I would like to be able to conditionally check that said prop is defined within the `<Hidden>`'s `when` prop, and the children *know* that, although the prop *could* be `undefined`, it's *not* because we've already checked. I essentially want the 's `when` prop to be considered an `if` statement for the Children.

Here's a sandbox to see the TypeScript error: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-v6r22q?file=/src/App.tsx:86-484

Below is the code within the sandbox

```
export default function App() {
  let id: string | undefined = undefined;
  if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
    id = "some-id";
  }
  return (
    <Hidden when={!!id}>
      {/*
       * I would like the child (`<ID />`) to know that
       * `id` is defined since we already checked that it
       * was within the Parent's (`<Hidden>`) `when` prop
       */}
      <ID id={id} />
    </Hidden>
  );
}
```

```
type HiddenProps = { when: boolean };

export const Hidden: FunctionComponent<HiddenProps> = (props) => {
  const { children, when } = props;
  return when ? <>{children}</> : null;
};
```

```
type IDProps = { id: string };

export const ID: FunctionComponent<IDProps> = (props) => {
  const { id } = props;
  return <div>{id}</div>;
};
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you want exactly is not currently possible in TSX, because JSX components do not act as TypeScript control flow structure elements.

The normal [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) syntax *does work* on the other hand:

```
function App() {
    let id: string | undefined = undefined;
    if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
        id = "some-id";
    }
    return (
        typeof id !== "undefined" &&
        //     ^? string | undefined
        <ID id={id} /> // Okay
        //      ^? string
    );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiArgHYbATEDCE4FSx8AvnAGZQ1wBEUqGnA3AChBMAJ5gkcAJIARAArswAZzgBeXHGAATAFxwlMKMGIBzOIyGCkAD0iw4aCgeky9RUjHJUakYvRgAPLIKEMoAfGpwABRgikoAlGoROIJwaQ5O8Hja5pGxoUpC6XA8MIRQxHABWsAAbmE42owBAPQ19UIWwiwkZBRwAIJgYFGJKcUANkjw2noGRqZwAD5wJFpILMZIWpFrG1taRenALNEAsigwABYAdFAoxFo0o3Bh6gAMNwCsY6nFxzt1JwlDQkABabQCP5pRjQkrTcqVKJw4piCQQU45ACEqiBe02fi0nDgADISSj0i0Wv8AHoAfgpaRaACpGWlmdI4AB3CCECY7CbAADWkmukjQV2A-OiAAMgjI4C0wjLEjAIHAhcQIFy4NdLmy4ByZdoZZoVOsCdt9MY0JIuZIUBMeCgtKIHFckGgRTs9TMYAaOVyUCoucBrsZdR64HIUDwGAByFRROUACW062IysSMq5HuIpvyYADLTZ8s0WlUjS0zCViupAHkhShRGyqf84PS4fFOoIgA)

Comment: Yeeeaahh...I have been able to get the normal conditional rendering syntax to work. Was just hoping I could do it differently.